# events without $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

Let's say in a service I need to make an http request and store the value, and then if something else uses the same service it could just reuse that stored value, without need of sending a request:

```
_cachedValue = null
.factory('myService', ($http, $q)->
    getFoo: ->
      dfrd = $q.defer()
      if _cachedValue == null  
         $http.get('/foo').success (data)->
           _cachedValue = data
           dfrd.resolve(_cachedValue)
      else
         dfrd.resolve(_cachedValue)
      return dfrd.promise
```

That kinda works. The problem is - when two consumers simultaneously try to invoke the method, it would send two requests. So I need to send the request only if it never has been sent, and when the second consumer invokes `getFoo`, it would just wait till the request comes through.

Repeatedly checking every few milliseconds until `_cachedValue`  isn't `null` - sounds pretty dumb, right? I can't `$watch` on the value change (there's no $scope inside the service). I can though utilize angular's event bus, and emit an event via `$rootScope`. But that sounds very overkill, since nobody outside of the service would be interested in listening to that kind of event. Can someone suggest a better way?

Comment: Hi, why not using the build in $http cache? see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: the problem is not the caching, the problem is to know if the request been sent and preventing it from being sent again. Yet it still has to know when request comes through

Comment: using `cache: true` will prevent it from being sent again

Comment: ok. but the question remains - is it possible to use eventbus without employing $rootScope?

Comment: @moderndegree is right, using cache: true will prevent it from being sent again, see : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L987

Comment: guys, set aside caching stuff, is it possible to use event bus without exposing things on the root scope?

Comment: You could do that by broadcasting events into an isolated scope

Answer (score 0):

You should only set the `$http` cache property to `true`.

This will prevent more request if a request is already in progress.

see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L987